# Rails 3 generate controller for a model not backed by a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Model in my Rails 3.1 app that is not backed by a table. In fact I did not even inherit from ActiveModel (which may have been a mistake...).

I wanted to use the generators to create a view really since this model has 67 attrs (user wants to occasionally specify what is in a certain attr and other times have it default).

When I run `rails g controller TestDataRecords index show edit new destroy create update` I do not get the views pre-populated.

Any thoughts?

Model

```
class TestDataRecord
  belongs_to :test_data_set

  attr_accessor :sample_attr # repeat 66 times


  def after_initilize
    return unless new_record?
    self.sample_attr = "default value"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out:
https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators
for a great gem that will give you the option to select the controller actions you want to generate views for.